# Excel Cell Date Format is not correct

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, cell

I need to have a correct Date format in Excel Cell because i can't sort the table with it.

Even if i changed the format cell i Always had the same issue

I already tried to fix that with changing the cell format with DATE but without success, sorting the table with the DATE is impossible.

Please someone had the same problem and what is the solutions to fix that ?

[image]

When i treid to fix it with this formula i got an error :

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(D2), D2, DATE(RIGHT(TRIM(D2),4), MID(D2,FIND("/",D2)+1,2), LEFT(TRIM(D2),2)))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spomZ.png)

Comment: Looks like you got values that they look like a date but they are not. Make sure those values have no extra blanks/spaces/not printable special chars (TRIM may be useful here). Make sure the cells are not in Text format. Try to convert them to numeric using VALUE and then try again to convert them to dates.

Comment: Ensure your dates in Excel are actually dates and not text strings that look like dates. You can do this by using `ISTEXT` function referencing the dates that are being misclassified. *Note: The cell number format does not alter the data type, so checking that is not a good method to differentiate.* The fix will depend on how the dates got into Excel in the first place, which you have not shared with us.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though your date column has a combination of properly formatted dates, and text strings that look like dates.

**Assumptions:**

Due to the cropping of your screenshot, it is unclear which column in your data set contains the dates. I will use column "D" in my solution below.

Due to the limited sample size of the incorrectly formatted dates, it is unclear if they should be interpreted as MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY. I will assume they are DD/MM/YYYY in my solution below.

**Solution:**

Insert a new column to the right of your Date column. To do this, right-click on the column header "E" and select "Insert".

Next, format the new column "E" as a "Short Date". To do this, on the Ribbon go to the **Home Tab > Number Group** and select "Short Date" from the Number Format drop down list.

In cell E2, use the following formula, then copy it down to the bottom of the data set:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(D2), D2, DATE(RIGHT(TRIM(D2),4), MID(D2,FIND("/",D2)+1,2), LEFT(TRIM(D2),2)))
```

Verify the new dates are correct. You can then **Copy** and **Paste Special > Values**, to overwrite the formulas with the correct date values.

**UPDATED:**

If I'm not mistaken "nous avons rencontré une erreur dans cette formule" is French, non?

If so, the Excel function equivalents applicable to this solution are as follows:

| English | French |
| --- | --- |
| IF | SI |
| ISNUMBER | ESTNUM |
| DATE | DATE |
| LEFT | GAUCHE |
| RIGHT | DROITE |
| MID | STXT |
| FIND | TROUVE |
| TRIM | SUPPRESPACE |

**Source:** [https://www.perfectxl.com](https://www.perfectxl.com/excel-glossary/what-is-excel-function/translations-french-english/)

If I've translated it correctly, the French version for the solution above should be:

```
=SI(ESTNUM(D2), D2, DATE(DROITE(SUPPRESPACE(D2),4), STXT(D2,TROUVE("/",D2)+1,2), GAUCHE(SUPPRESPACE(D2),2)))
```

I hope that works! ;-)

Comment: this formula doesn't fix my issue, i had an error message

Comment: It should work, with the correct range references. To assist you further, please edit your question to provide an additional screenshot of the attempt you made. Be sure the formula bar is visible (with the formula you tried), as well as the table/column headers and the date column you are trying to convert.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Samir. I believe the problem is that our system language settings are different. I've edited my answer to include the French function equivalents to the English solution. Try it out, as I am unable to test it fully on my system.